# Why is my Array List Printing incorrectly the second time?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Is there something about Array List properties that I'm missing here?

I'm adding a list of custom objects to my list, each one with a unique name.

When I access the list a second time, every object in the list is the same. There is no code between accesses when I tested this.

```
   // Add all the Tastr Items to the Array list using the list of restaurants found by yelp.
    for (int i = 0; i < yelp.getRestaurants().size(); i++){
        TastrItem temp = new TastrItem();
        temp.setRestaurant(yelp.getRestaurants().get(i));
        itemList.add(temp);
        System.out.println("First Time Accessing the list --- > " + itemList.get(i).getRestaurant());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < yelp.getRestaurants().size(); i++) {
        System.err.println("Second time Accessing the list  --- > " + itemList.get(i).getRestaurant());
    }
```

Output:

```
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Stanton's City Bites
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Aladdin Mediterranean Cuisine
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > The Breakfast Klub
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > M&M Grill
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Big & Juicy Juice Bar
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Eddie V's Prime Seafood
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Baby Barnaby's Café
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Pappas Bros Steakhouse
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Just Dinner
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Green Seed Vegan
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Local Foods
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Salad Extraveganza
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Luigi's Pizzeria
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Houston's Restaurant
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Hugo's
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Huynh Restaurant
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > MKT BAR
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Reef
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Mockingbird Bistro
I/System.out: First Time Accessing the list --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
W/System.err: Second time Accessing the list  --- > Pho Saigon Vietnamese
```

Edit: The answer is that the Restaurant variable was **static** in the Tastr Item Class.

Comment: What does `yelp.getRestaurants().get(i)` do? Is it the `get()` of the `List` interface or some custom method?

Comment: its the get method from ArrayList. It returns the size, IE the amount of restaurants found.

Comment: You would have to post the code for `TastrItem`. I suspect you have a static variable there.

Comment: Like @lionscribe is suggesting, you are modifying the `List` before the second loop runs and it only contains the last element from the last iteration.

Comment: try adding the items directly? `itemsList.add(yelp.getRestaurants().get(i))`

Comment: @lionscribe Thank you. I had an auto generated static variable it that was causing the issue. If you'd like to post that as the answer I will accept it. Otherwise I'll post the answer myself and paste in some example code.

Comment: I just added the answer. I appreciate your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that in the `TastrItem` class, you are saving the item to a static variable. Therefore, though you are correctly creating a new `TastrItem` in each loop, the static variable is always set to the last value. To solve this, just edit the `TastrItem` class, and remove the static keyword.